# Insert Line Break into XtraGrid Cells

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I'm creating a calendar view for an employee's shift schedule.

[image]

Basically, what I need to do is replace the " - " in the Cells with a line break so that the cell would be shown as:

```
|--------|
|Saturday|
|--------|
|   1    |
|   O2   |
----------
```

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`RepositoryItemMemoEdit`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemMemoEdittopic) as your [`ColumnEdit`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsGridColumn_ColumnEdittopic). It allows to use line breaks in cells.
Here is example:

```
var edit = new RepositoryItemMemoEdit();

foreach (GridColumn column in gridView1.Columns)
    column.ColumnEdit = edit;

gridView1.SetRowCellValue(1, gridView1.Columns[0], "2\n02");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) RepositoryItemMemoEdit() this was what I needed all along.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ColumnView.CustomColumnDisplayText](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_CustomColumnDisplayTexttopic.aspx) event and there you can split the text with `'-'` or replace with `Environment.NewLine`.

Second approach, Use the [HTML Text Formatting](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument4874) for the grid editor. See the [search result](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=xtragrid%20html%20text) for this approach.

**References:**
[Unable to display HTML text in XtraGrid](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q399678)